# Array Size Declaration Differences For C and C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

```
const int num = 16;
struct inputs{
       double X1[num];
       double X2[num];
};
```

Gives me an error:

> error: variably modified ‘X1’ at file scope

The same was true for 'X2'.

But I remember the above is fine for C++, the above is fine (I may be mistaken for C++).

Can anybody clarify this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference. In C, a `const` variable still isn't treated as a true compile-time constant (officially, it's not allowed a part of a `constant expression`), so this isn't allowed. Note, however, that although C doesn't require that the compiler allow it, the standard does give permission for an implementation to accept other forms of constant expressions, so it's free to accept it if it chooses.

In C++, a `const` variable is treated as a constant, so it is allowed.

Interestingly, roughly the reverse is true when you use a value passed as a function parameter:

```
void f(int size) { 
    int array[size];
}
```

This *is* allowed in C, but not in C++. This is a `variably modified` array; the error message you're getting is basically trying to tell you that these are only allowed inside functions.

Comment: In C, you can pass the size of an array to a function? Learned ! Thanks!

Comment: @Rich: yes, but only if your compiler conforms with C99 (at least in this respect) -- this was not included in C89/90 (though it was a fairly common extension even with older compilers).

Answer (score 8):

I can point you to a [C FAQ: I don't understand why I can't use const values in initializers and array dimensions](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constasconst.html).

What it basically says is that `num` isn't a true constant, it's just read-only. To get a true constant you would need a `#define num 16`.

Also on that page: **C is unlike C++ in this regard**.

Answer (score 0):

Not in struct. You can do it in local scope.

Comment: Even for C? According to other answers, it is not possible for C. maybe ok for C++?

Comment: I'd trust Adam, because I don't remember exact standards. His version sounds plausible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a constant value. So in C you have to use a `#define` in this regard. For C++ it would have been fine.

Use this instead:

```
#define num 16
struct inputs{
  double X1[num];
  double X2[num];
};
```

Comment: Bad choice of word, meant regard.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, compile time constants can be used as lengths in array declarations and `const` variables (only some of them) can be compile-time constants. This is why it will work in C++.

C, however, has a feature that looks similar, the variable-length array. It means you can use any integer expression (even runtime computed) as array length, but only for local variables. This is why your compiler complains about "variably modified ‘X1’ *at file scope*".

Answer (score 0):

As already said by others C and C++ are different regarding constant integer expressions.

But you don't have to use a macro as others suggested to have code that works with both. If you want to do it with "scope" you can do it with an enumeration constant. Something like

```
enum { num = 16 };
struct inputs {
  double X1[num];
  double X2[num];
};
```

will work for both, regardless if you put this in file or function scope.